# Custom TableViewCell not Displaying Accessory

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've done many apps with simple tableviews and I'm comfortable with them.  I've never used a custom tableViewCell until today.   I started with a really custom cell with two labels and that renders normally.   I can populate my two labels with my data, no problem.  I thought it would be equally easy to add the standard checkmark using:

cell.accessoryType =  .Checkmark

My cells render the labels properly but I don't get a checkmark.  Is there something extra I need to do to render an accessory type with a custom tableViewCell?

edit:  I tried to not just use a default accessoryType.   I created an image, an imageview, and set cell.accessoryView to that view and that doesn't display either.   Obviously I'm missing something in my custom cell

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    // your cell coding here and set cell accessory view checkmark  
    cell.accessoryType = IUTableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

}
```

Comment: I am using swift and I get an unresolved external error for UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` consist of 2 subviews:

- contentView
- accessoryView

When you are creating your own custom cell (that extends `UITableViewCell`) add your views to contentView. ([See docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7))

It is possible that you have added your views directly to UITableViewCell and in this case you are drawing your subviews on top of accessoryView.